How to remove masking of particular attribute in Airflow Operator
I am using DatabricksSubmitRunOperator and setting a templated json parameter. When I look at Rendered Template, I see that idempotency_token attribute is masked with ***. This is surely done by the global masking of sensitive values configuration. And it totally makes sense - it's fair to assume that generally tokens are sensitive. But not all tokens are.
Is it possible to configure exemption from masking, for example per operator? Operator should know which parts of it's configuration are sensitive and which not.
Screenshot from Airflow UI:

